# Can I determine the zero value of generic types?

Tags: rust

The closest I managed to find was the `std::num::Int` and `std::num::Float`  traits, which define `zero()`. However, they are specific to primitive types.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, because it doesn't make sense in general.  In fact, there are several types where "zero" is *very specifically* **not** valid at all.  For example, if you were to take an appropriately-sized zero value and transmute it into a `Box`, that would violate memory safety!

There's an alternative to "zero", which is the [`Default`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait.  It allows you to say `Default::default()` to get a type's "default" value, whatever that happens to be.  However, there's no consistent, sensible definition of "default" for all types.  As such, you can only use it for types which *explicitly* implement it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to correct my misconception and explain why it is wrong. I come from a C background where the concepts of 0 and default are more or less interchangeable.